# How to run "python setup.py test" without installing "extras_require" dependencies?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tensorflow, setuptools

I have `extras_require` dependencies in a `setup.cfg` listed as:

```
[extras_require]
tensorflow = tensorflow
tensorflow_gpu = tensorflow-gpu
```

That way if my package is installed with `pip install pkg[tensorflow_gpu]`, it installs one version of the package, vs `pip install pkg[tensorflow]` which installs the other.

This is similar to how the [Edward Package](https://github.com/blei-lab/edward/blob/master/setup.py) packages (following this [git issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7166)).

However, when I run `python setup.py test`, it installs **both** `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` packages before executing my unit tests. That can be problematic once I `import tensorflow` in any unit tests, and is hardware-dependent.

Is there a way to selectively install a certain `extras_require` package when running `python setup.py test`?

Alternately is there a way to install **no** `extras_require` packages? Because then I can install `tensorflow` before running the test command.

(Note: I understand I can run pip and pytest independently, but I'm looking for a solution that uses `setuptools`)

Comment: Can you please include the `setup.py` for your package? The direct dependency for `tensorflow` might be hard-coded there, or in one of the dependencies that your package specified.

Comment: `python setup.py test` is no longer supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this is not a `setuptools` issue, but rather a potential issue with the tool I am using called `pyscaffold`. I opened a [question issue](https://github.com/pyscaffold/pyscaffold/issues/228) on their github.

When I run `python setup.py test` with the following `setup.cfg`, it works fine, as in it does not pull in tensorflow.

```
[metadata]
name = simple

[options]
package_dir = 
    =src
setup_requires = pytest-runner
install_requires = 
tests_require = pytest

[options.extras_require]
tf = tensorflow

[aliases]
test = pytest

[tool:pytest]
addopts = --verbose
testpaths = tests
```